# RecyclerView - Difference between computeHorizontalScrollRange and computeHorizontalScrollExtent?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

RecyclerView is powerful, but it's features aren't well documented. I've been trying to compute the "total scrollable area" within an inflated RecyclerView and found my luck with this expression =

```
"recyclerView.computeHorizontalScrollRange() - recyclerView.computeHorizontalScrollExtent()"
```

But I don't really understand what exactly computeHorizontalScrollRange() does and what computeHorizontalScrollExtent() does. Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured. The answer is implicit when you understand the meaning of the words 'Range' and 'Extent'.

Range - The area of variation between upper and lower limits on a particular scale.

Extent - The particular degree to which something is or is believed to be the case.

Comment: That doesn't make it clear at all to me. Could you elaborate?